# Custom Serialize List of Objects in Jackson

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have a method which does the following:

```
    final DaySerializer daySerializer = new DaySerializer(Day.class);
    final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    final SimpleModule module = new SimpleModule("DaySerializer", new Version(2, 1, 3, null, null, null));
    module.addSerializer(Day.class, daySerializer);

    mapper.registerModule(module);
    try {
        mapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValue(new File(this.jsonPath + "/Days.json"), days);

    } catch (final Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

And the serializer class method:

```
@Override
public void serialize(final Day day, final JsonGenerator jsonGenerator, final SerializerProvider serializerProvider)
        throws IOException {

    jsonGenerator.writeStartObject();
    //Date
    SimpleDateFormat format1 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    jsonGenerator.writeStringField("calendar", "" + format1.format(day.getCalendar().getTime()));
    //Day index
    jsonGenerator.writeNumberField("dayCount", day.getDayCount());

    //Demand
    for (final Entry<String, int[]> e : day.getDemand().entrySet()) {
        jsonGenerator.writeFieldName("Demand: "+e.getKey());
        jsonGenerator.writeStartArray();
        for(int i : e.getValue()) {
            jsonGenerator.writeNumber(i);
        }
        jsonGenerator.writeEndArray();  
    }

    //Employee shift allocations
    for(EmployeeShiftAllocation eSA : day.getEmployeeShiftAllocations()) {
        jsonGenerator.writeNumberField("eSA ID", eSA.getId());
    }


    jsonGenerator.writeEndObject();
}
```

Which works for the first Day object in the List which is handed in to it, but doesn't show any errors, but only exports the first Day object. This is confusing since I do hand in the List. Am I missing something simple? Do I need to handle this inside the serializer somehow?

Comment: Can you provide more code and specify Jackson version you are using?

Comment: Do you mean that serialization only includes the first value? That should not be the case: `List` (or array) should be handled by Jackson just fine, calling custom serializer for each element, separately.
But one thing you should try for troubleshooting is to see what happens when `List` is a property of a POJO: there are some difference to handling of the "root value" (direct value being serialized) and values reached via properties. This might give a clue to problem you jave.

Comment: @DmitryZvorygin what code? I think that's everything that's relevant? Jackson v2.9

Comment: @StaxMan Ah interesting. Yes the serializer only appears to be called once, with the output only including the first element in the array (in this case there are 90 day objects, only day 0 is appearing). Good point, I'll test this with a String list or something soon. Thanks!

Comment: @KenReid, I mean minimum example, where you actually add at least two elements in the collection and see that only first one is being serialized. Maybe there's a bug in the code that we don't see, and you actually pass collection with one element only. So, just minimum working example that would reproduce your problem so that we could compile and run it locally.

Comment: @KenReid just to be sure: I did NOT mean different element type like `String`, but rather that `List` would be contained within a POJO, as property.